# How can i simplify this for loop?

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop, simplify

I need to fill a 360 element matrix with periods of 90 elements for different phiStart and phiExit values:

```
flute    = 4;
phiStart = 0;
phiExit  = 90;
phiDelta = 1;
phiPitch = 360 / flute;

for g = 0:abs(phiExit - phiStart);
    for k = 0:abs(phiExit - phiStart);
        for j = 0:abs(phiExit - phiStart);
            for m = 0:abs(phiExit - phiStart);
                for i = 0:abs(phiExit - phiStart);
                    answerA = phiStart + i * phiDelta;
                    phi(i+1) = answerA;
                end
                answerA = phiStart + m * phiDelta;
                phi(m + phiPitch) = answerA;
            end
            answerA = phiStart + j * phiDelta;
            phi(j + 2 * phiPitch) = answerA;
        end
        answerA = phiStart + k * phiDelta;
        phi(k + 3 * phiPitch) = answerA;
    end
    answerA = phiStart + g * phiDelta;
    phi(g + 4 * phiPitch) = answerA;
end

b = (phi > 0);  % dummy matrix for edge cofficients
h = feedRate * sin(phi / 180 * pi);
```

Comment: What language is this? (Matlab?)

Comment: 'phiStart' and 'phiDelta' are constants. Why do you need the nesting loops? Are any 'phi' values being overwritten again and again?

Comment: Yes phiStart and phiExit are constants defined by me. I need to fill a matrix like this. lets say a row matrix with 15 members. phiStart=2 phiExit=4  and the period is 5 -----> Thus matrix should be [2 3 4 0 0  2 3 4 0 0 2 3 4 0 0]                                                                                      I need to solve that in simpliest way for a matrix with 360 members                The language is matlab.   Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this makes no sense (just trying to help), I don't even know in what language it is written, but what I read in the original code points to something like

```
for i = 0:abs(phiExit - phiStart);
    answerA = phiStart + i * phiDelta;
    for j = 0:abs(flute - 1)
        phi(i + j * phiPitch) = answerA;
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. This is the solution